# IOHK Dev Workflow

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, iohk

Is there a standardised workflow for testing our smart contracts (i.e. something different than copy and paste from Vim into the playground) ?

All the best !

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

In the first video introducing the first lecture Lars talks about "ways" to test our smart contacts... I think I remember he says that this will be part of the program but later on...

On the other hand he said that there are no best practices yet because plutus (and the playground) is a brand new language (and Dev environment/ ecosystem)...

I hope we can find out all these topics soon.